# Why block explorer shows that I have ether but ethereum wallet show 0 balance

Tags: go-ethereum

In testnet etherscan I can see 18.5 ether in my account:

https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/address/0x3838312050E71973d908211F51FCFEBF16428AbF

But in the Ethereum Wallet, I cannot see any money, even when it wrote that blocks are up to date. I started Geth by typing `geth --testnet`

I looked at the latest block in testnet and it is `467662`. However, in the Geth output, it displays something like `number=1228242`

Answer (score 0):

Your `geth` synchronizes with Ropsten rather than Rinkeby.  In Rospten, block [#1228242](https://ropsten.etherscan.io/block/1228242) was mined on Jul-02-2017 08:53:36 PM +UTC, about the same time block [#467662](https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/block/467662) was mined in Rinkeby (Jul-02-2017 08:10:58 PM +UTC).

Try running `get` with `--rinkeby` instead of `--testnet` option.